# Apache doesn't recognize PHP using a Mac

Tags: php, macos, apache

Today, I installed PHP, MySQL and Apache on my brandnew Mac, but for some reason Apache doesn't recognize the PHP extension... I followed [this](http://www.coolestguyplanet.net/how-to-install-php-mysql-apache-on-os-x-10-6/) tutorial (just like last time) and for some reason the `phpinfo.php` file is showing nothing more then this:

```
<?php 
     phpinfo();
?>
```

What setting or configuration did I miss?

Comment: `brandnew Mac` good.....

Comment: What's wrong wit a `brandnew Mac`?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html)?

It installs all of them for you, it's free, and you simply have to open an app to launch both the MySQL and Apache severs.

Comment: Maybe I'll try it, but i still would like to know what I missed during the setup of Apache...

Comment: I was considering installing them all manually, then I tried MAMP :)

Comment: Do I need to uninstall the previous installations? Or does MAMP overrides them all? Cause I can't launch my MySQL server...

Comment: ah - that can happen the first time - go in activity monitor, search mysqld, and kill all the processes called that - once you've done that, it should work

Comment: also to access your DB after that go to localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin

Comment: Can I configure a `vhost`-file with MAMP?

Comment: I don't know what a vhost file is :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your `httpd.conf`.  You might find that the PHP module load command is commented out.